# Detecting Email Clients with Dynamic Image

Tags: php, email, detection, animated-gif

I am wondering if it is possible to serve a different image to particular email clients that don't support animated gifs. I know it is possible to use PHP to dynamically generate an image.

So if there is something like User Agent strings that can be read when the email client sends a request to download the Dynamic Image i.e. `<img src="http://myserver.com/someimage.php" />` then php could send a different image to the email clients that don't support animated gifs.

Is this possible or is there a comparable work around for sniffing out animated gif support and serving up a alternative image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks to profitPHP who suggest image logging. I have come up with the below...

```
<?php 
// Find needle in User Agent Hay Stack
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$isLotus = strpos($useragent,'Lotus-Notes');
$isMsoffice = strpos($useragent,'MSOffice');

// Route request to supported image
if ($isLotus === false && $isMsoffice === false) {
    header('Content-type: image/gif');
    readfile('images/email-announcement_02.gif');
} else {
    header('Content-type: image/gif');
    readfile('images/noAnim_02.gif');   
}
?>
```

This will find the Lotus Notes or MS Outlook versions that do not support .GIF animations. You can change the readfile to be your own local files.

I have tested this on Outlook 2001-2010 and lotus Notes 6-8 and it serves the appropriate image to the appropriate version.

Answer (score 3):

Start testing it out.  Fire up a client that doesn't support it, send yourself the message in question, and look at the HTTPD logs.  You're probably gonna have to code this on a case by case basis.

Comment: ever done anything like this?  Do you have a resource that I might consult for starting out on User Agent detection?

Comment: make your image tag in the email point to http://yourserver.com/imagelogger.php.  In that script, log the $_SERVER variables to a log file, see what you get.  Also you can check the Apache/IIS logs and get some info about the request that way.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't ever hear of an email client that would not support animated gifs, unless perhaps for size reasons.

My understanding is that there are 2 types of images you can put into an email. The first is an attached image, in which you send the image with the email as part of the email. The second is an external image in which you reference an image off of a website.

I think what you want to look into is sending a MIME email. If you google php mime you will come up with a a lot of results.

Essentially this will allow you to send one email that is in different parts depending on the clients ability. From experience I have sent MIME emails that were html and text only. Because some email clients do not accept html messages.

I hope this gives you some direction.

Comment: Outlook 2007 and 2010 do not support animated gifs.  (Neither, I believe do Lotus Notes 6 or 7).